# Identify the nth checkbox from checkbox group

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

In one of the Web application which I am automating has 10 checkboxes in checkbox group with group id and group name. 
Now I have to select the 7th checkbox using Selenium WebDriver.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: try assigning "value" attribute to each checkbox html tag.

Comment: can you post the html of the checkbox group?

Answer (score 2):

You can write an index based xpath for your check boxes and as rao_555 stated in comments if there is a value associated with each checkbox you can write an xpath based on checkboxes values.

Answer (score 1):

Use a naming convention for your checkboxes: CB01, CB02, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath locator

```
//*[@id='checkbox_group_id']/input[7]
```

should do the trick. This will select the 7th input child element of the element with the `id` of `checkbox_group_id`.